# Deduction of Hamiltonian using Fourier coeficients on a vector potential $\vec{A}$

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, fourier-transform, hamiltonian

> Given the operator $\vec{A}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{V}} \sum_{\vec{k}, \alpha} \varepsilon^{\alpha}\left(c_{\vec{k}, \alpha}(t) e^{i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}-\omega_{k} t\right)}+c_{\vec{k}, \alpha}^{*}(t) e^{-i\left(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{r}-\omega_{k} t\right)}\right)$ and using $H=\frac{1}{2} \int d^{3} r\left(|E|^{2}+|B|^{2}\right)$. Show that $H=\sum_{\vec{k}, \alpha} 2\left(\frac{\omega}{c}\right)^{2} c_{\vec{k}, \alpha}^{*} c_{\vec{k}, \alpha}$.

Well, I did almost everything, but I can't seem to be able to do the last step, since $c$ and $c^{*}$ do not comutate, as far as I know.

The result I have so far is:

$H=\frac{1}{2} \int d^{3} r\left(|\vec{E}|^{2}+|\vec{B}|^{2}\right)=\sum_{\vec{k}, \alpha}  k^{2}\left(c_{\vec{k}, \alpha} c_{\vec{k}, \alpha}^{*}+c_{\vec{k}, \alpha}^{*} c_{\vec{k}, \alpha}\right)$

The fact the classes are online is frustrating me. I do not have contact with my colleges and they don't seem to care about discuss exercises in whatsapp since I do not know anyone because my Masters began with the pandemic. That's why I'm back here.

Comment: Assuming you are working in Coulomb gauge, the creation and annihilation operators satisfy $[c_{\vec{k},\alpha},c^\dagger_{\vec{k'},\alpha'}]=\delta_{\alpha,\alpha'}(2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{k}-\vec{k}')$. You can use this commutation relation to do the final step.

Comment: So, since $k$ and $k'$ are different, it means $c$ and $c*$ commutate in this case? Could you tell me where can I find more details about this? I found in the professor notes that this $c(t)$ is probably wrong and it should be $c(0)$  and also that this is considered a classic case.

Comment: In your expression you actually have $c_k c^\dagger_k$ (same $k$). So you will get the answer you are looking for when you commute $c$ and $c^\dagger$, but you will also get a term proportional to $\delta(0)$ from the commutator that corresponds to an infinite vacuum energy term (related to the cosmological constant). You can think of it as an infinite constant and ignore it. [David Tong's QFT notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) are a good reference, especially relevant for your problem are Sections 2 and 6.

Comment: Actually you have to be a little careful, the commutation relation I wrote is valid in the continuum limit $V\rightarrow \infty$. I think you should replace $(2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(0)$ with $V$ in the "box normalization" you are using (but please double check). Anyway this doesn't affect the point that you should get "the answer you are looking for" + "an infinite constant contribution to the energy".